# What is this vintage 1979 IC: General Instrument PB8300 in PDIP 14 package?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

In one of the drawers of electronic components I've accumulated since middle school (late 1970s), there is one integrated circuit I have so far been unable to identify (yes, only one* thanks to the internet).
Markings are:

**PB8300 - [GI Logo] 7947 TAIWAN**

Here's a photograph of the mystery IC:

[image: General Instrument PB8300 Integrated Circuit]

There are no markings on the underside.  The logo is [General Instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument).  I presume that "7947" is the date code, so I located online copies of several [catalogs from GI](https://www.rsp-italy.it/Electronics/Databooks/General%20Instrument/index.htm) from the 1978-1983 era, and none of the listed product codes start with "PB".  Any ideas what it is?

One possibility:  Some of the parts I have were unused samples that my father got from colleagues at the Zenith Radio Company (later Zenith Electronics), so they might be television-related.

*Transistors are another story entirely.  I have heaps of TO-92 and TO-5 that I have no data on.

Comment: Try probing it with a DMM set to diode-check mode.  Can likely determine if it is a discrete array or digital chip just by seeing forward-diode-drops in a discernable order.

Comment: GI was pretty advanced in all areas. They owned Intellivision (game)  Scientific Atlanta (RF Video) and bought our DS1 to the home network TV,voice + data with patents for our broadband WAN in that era. (Project Ida). Their prefix letters stand for the chip function and I did not know they started the Processor IC “PIC1650 series” at that time, now Microchip.  Good luck it’s proprietary for some project. Like “Phone B.....”

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yes, I noticed the letter codes relating to function in the catalogs.  I thought it was pretty interesting to see the 1977 datasheets for what were already the second-generation PIC microcontrollers then.  (Also fun fact that the Intellivision CPU shared a common lineage with the DEC PDP-11, one of which I had access to at my high school.)